# Read in file with Inconsistent record separators/rows

Tags: perl

I'm reading a text file of product catalogue line by line to input the (split) rows into my database.  Issue is:  the product_description column has line breaks within it, which means when the file is read in line by line, the description breaks onto multiple lines making the process difficult.

In Excel, (spreadsheet), the description shows on one line, as if without line breaks.
In Open Office Calc, (spreadsheet) the description breaks onto several lines; a number of lines which is inconsistent across all records.

I can identify each start line because each record starts with a UPC/SKU of less than 12 chars.

I'm seeking guidance as to the better way to do this....

If reading line by line, should I split each line into an array so that if the $array[0] less than 12 chars, we know it is the beginning of a new record. If it is not, then we can push that array value onto $array[9] of the preceding line, which is the product_description string.
Here's the code so far. It creates the hash correctly but, I wonder, if there's a simpler way to get rid of unnecessary line breaks within a spreadsheet column. (Apart from them not being put in in the first instance. lol).

```
my $csv_file ='/home/domain/public_html/csv-files-for-read-in/filename.csv';

open my $data, '<', $csv_file
or die("<$csv_file> could not be opened for reading <$!>");

my $record_id;
my %description_hash;

while ( my $line = <$data> ) 
{
$line =~ s/""//g;
  
  # ignore empty lines
  if ( $line !~ /[a-zA-Z0-9]/ )
  {
  next;
  }
  
  
my @lines = split( ',' , $line);
my $length = length($lines[0]);


  if ( $length < 12 )
  {
  # we are starting a new record
  $record_id = $lines[0];
  my $desc = $lines[18];
  $description_hash{$record_id} = $desc;
  } 
  else
  {
  #we are adding on to the description 
  my $description_addition = $lines[0];
  my $desc = $description_hash{$record_id};
  my $new_desc = (join( ' ', ( $desc, $description_addition ) ) );
  $description_hash{$record_id}=$new_desc;
  }

}
```

Comment: [Text::CSV_XS](http://p3rl.org/Text::CSV_XS) and [Text::CSV](http://p3rl.org/Text::CSV) can both handle CSVs with quoted newlines.

Comment: Thank you choroba. Some useful reading for me. :)

Comment: You do need to specify `binary => 1`